# How to catch crash without disturbing the normal crash flow

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-fragments, crash

I know there are already good tools available like `crashlytics`, but i have a requirment and i can't use these tools.

All i need to is to save the crash log before application exists, and that without disturbing the normal flow, and using any 3rd party library

I have implemented this, but it has disturb the normal flow of android crashing. I want to save the log, but don't want to disturb the normal crashing flow.

This is what i am doing to save the crash log.

```
    public void registerCrash(){

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler()
        {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
            {
                handleUncaughtException (thread, e);
            }
        });
    } 


    public void handleUncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e)
    {
        thread.getStackTrace();
        savePreferenceData(e.toString());
        System.exit(0);
    }


    public void savePreferenceData(String data) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= context.getSharedPreferences(LOG_DATA, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        prefsEditor.putString(STACK_TRACE, data);
        prefsEditor.apply();
}
```

The problem is that, It restarts the application, without giving the default Alert dialog to user. `Unfortunately App has stopped.`

Kindly guide me how to save crash log witout disturbing the normal crash mechanisim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before setting the UncaughtExceptionHandler, keep track of the one that was set before and simply call it from your own handler after you are done:

```
private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultExceptionHandler;

public void registerCrash(){
    defaultExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler(){
        @Override
        public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e){
            handleUncaughtException (thread, e);
            if(defaultExceptionHandler != null){
                defaultExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(thread, e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Let me try this.

Comment: This is taking the crash thing into loop, It crashes for the first time, it goes to handleUnCaughException, then it checks `defaultExceptionHandler != null`, which is true, and it goes to `defaultExceptionHandler.uncaughtException` which takes the program into the loop

Comment: Then you probably call the method more than once and thus use your own UncaughtExceptionHandler as the default one.

Comment: The problem occurs when we have multiple crashes, It goes into loop in that case. There are some cases when 3 or 4 crashes happens, Let say `Map Fragment` is crashed, with it, the activity containing it, is also crashed, and some other activity which is carrying the reference is also crashed. In this case there are 3 crashes, and this logic goes into loop. If there is 1 crash, it works fine.

Comment: That can only happen if you call that method multiple times. try a null check if(defaultExceptionHandler==null){ defaultExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(); }

Comment: If i use; `if(defaultExceptionHandler==null){` it hangs application after the crash,and not because its in a loop, but there is nothing to do. The value is `not null` and it does not call ` defaultExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(thread, e);`

Comment: I have added more details here.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45402231/how-to-override-handleuncaughtexception-without-changing-its-functionallity