# How to override handleUncaughtException without changing its functionallity

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, exception

I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44196112/4977669) question some time back on `Stackoverflow`, the answer worked for me, It overrides the`handleUncaughtException`, I save the exception and throws the default `Unfortunately app has stopped working`, but when i integrated this in my app, I am facing an issue.

This is the answer i got.

```
private Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultExceptionHandler;

    public void registerCrash(){
        defaultExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler(){
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e){
                handleUncaughtException (thread, e);
                if(defaultExceptionHandler != null){
                    defaultExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(thread, e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

What it does, first it goes to `handleUncaughtException (thread, e);` i save the crash log in this method, then it reads this line

```
 if(defaultExceptionHandler != null){
    defaultExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(thread, e);
}
```

here we throw uncaught exception again, so it goes to the first line again, and again saves the exception, and this goes in loop, and application becomes not responding.

What i want is to save crash log, and then show the default `Unfortunate` message to user.

**EDIT**

On Application launch it reads this;

```
defaultExceptionHandler = Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();
```

When application crashes, it reads these lines

```
Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler (new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler(){
    @Override
    public void uncaughtException (Thread thread, Throwable e){

        handleUncaughtException (thread, e); //Custom Method 

        if(defaultExceptionHandler != null){
            defaultExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(thread, e);
        }
    }
```

So it first goes to `handleUncaughtException()` there i have provided custom implementation, then it goes to this;

```
if(defaultExceptionHandler != null){
  defaultExceptionHandler.uncaughtException(thread, e);
}
```

The `defaultExceptionHandler` is never null; So it goes in a loop in case of multiple crashes.

I have tried adding `count` there, but it was `0` each time.

Comment: `So it goes in a loop in case of multiple crashes` can you point out a scenario this happens? What causes another exception to happen?

Comment: @azizbekian : I was unable to find out the steps to reporduce of it.This does not happen everytime, but sometimes

Comment: what is defaultExceptionHandler method. Is it your own method? if yes post that method code. And post handleUncaughtException (thread, e) method code too

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace to post. does defaultExceptionHandler.uncaughtException do system.exit? It could be throwing a securityexception

Comment: Also what does "On Application launch it reads this" mean? (Where do you do it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that your `registerCrash()` method is being called twice.

The first time, you register `Handler 1`; there is no default handler at this point, so it sets `defaultExceptionHandler` to `null`.  The second time, you register  `Handler 2`, and then update `defaultExceptionHandler` to point to `Handler 1`.

On an uncaught exception, `Handler 2` gets invoked first.  It calls your custom handler method, then invokes `defaultExceptionHandler`, which now points to `Handler 1`.

`Handler 1` gets invoked.  It calls your custom handler method a second time, then it invokes `defaultExceptionHandler`, **which now points to itself**.  This step repeats until your stack overflows.

I suggest two changes.  First, add a guard to ensure you only register your crash handler once.  Second, don't store the fallback handler in a field; capture it in a closure so the value seen by your handler never changes.

```
private static final AtomicBoolean CRASH_HANDLER_REGISTERED = new AtomicBoolean();

public void registerCrash() {
    if (CRASH_HANDLER_REGISTERED.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        final Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler defaultHandler =
            Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler();

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(
            new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
                @Override
                public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable e) {
                    handleUncaughtException(thread, e); // Custom Method

                    if (defaultHandler != null) {
                        defaultHandler.uncaughtException(thread, e);
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try another approach, avoid overriding exceptions, catch it and retrive the error code, and do this:

`when x code with x conditions verify, do that`